# Downloading Docusign Signed File, but file data is encrypted

Tags: docusignapi

When I am trying to download the DocuSign Signed File, it is being downloaded but
the issue is that the file had some dropdowns and textboxes, and in downloaded file, the dropdowns and textboxes display encrypted data and not the real filled data, and one more issue is there, after the completion of document, I received the signed file on my email but the selected dropdown value overlaps over the following textbox and the signed pdf becomes non-readable.
The code for downloading the file goes like this

```
// read how many documents are in the envelope
int docCount = docsList.EnvelopeDocuments.Count;
string filePath = null;
FileStream fs = null;

// loop through the envelope's documents and download each doc
for (int i = 0; i < docCount; i++)
{
    // GetDocument() API call returns a MemoryStream
    MemoryStream docStream = (MemoryStream)envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, docsList.EnvelopeDocuments[i].DocumentId);
    // let's save the document to local file system
    filePath = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".pdf";
    fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    docStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    docStream.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Envelope Document {0} has been downloaded to:  {1}", i, filePath);
}
```

But the downloaded file will look like this with encrypted data
[image]

And this is the following document which I received on email after completion of the document, the first column is dropdown selected value which overlaps
[image]

This is how envelope request is created

```cs
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.EmailSubject = _objLOA.Subject;
envDef.EmailBlurb = _objLOA.EmailBody;
string recipientEmail = _objLOA.ToEmail;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_objLOA.RecipientName))
{
    _objLOA.RecipientName = "Animesh";
}
string recipientName = _objLOA.RecipientName;
string templateRoleName = "Customer";
string TemplateId = "xxxxxx";

// assign recipient to template role by setting name, email, and role name.  Note that the
// template role name must match the placeholder role name saved in your account template.  
TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();

var dropdownItems1 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems2 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems3 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems4 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems5 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems6 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems7 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems8 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems9 = new List<ListItem>();
var dropdownItems10 = new List<ListItem>();

dropdownItems1.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
dropdownItems2.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
dropdownItems3.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
dropdownItems4.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
}); 
dropdownItems5.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
dropdownItems6.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
dropdownItems7.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
dropdownItems8.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
dropdownItems9.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
dropdownItems10.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = "Select",
    Value = "-1",
    Selected = "true"
});
foreach (Utility itemUtility in _objutilityList)
{
    dropdownItems1.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems2.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems3.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems4.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems5.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems6.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems7.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems8.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems9.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
    dropdownItems10.Add(new ListItem()
    {
        Text = itemUtility.Name,
        Value = itemUtility.Id.ToString()

    });
}
List<Text> _listText = new List<Text>();              
int rowNumber = 1;

foreach(LOACustomerData _loaresponseitem in _objLOA.LOACustomerData)
{

    Text itemTextESI = new Text();
    Text itemTextAddress = new Text();                           
    itemTextESI.TabLabel = "txtESI" + rowNumber;
    itemTextESI.OriginalValue = _loaresponseitem.AccountNumber;
    itemTextESI.Value = _loaresponseitem.AccountNumber;

    itemTextAddress.TabLabel = "txtServiceAddress" + rowNumber;
    itemTextAddress.OriginalValue = _loaresponseitem.ServiceAddress;
    itemTextAddress.Value = _loaresponseitem.ServiceAddress;

    _listText.Add(itemTextAddress);
    _listText.Add(itemTextESI);
    if (rowNumber == 1)
    {
        ListItem item = dropdownItems1.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString());
        if(item!=null)
            item.Selected = "true";
    }
    else if (rowNumber == 2)
    {
        dropdownItems2.Find(x => x.Value == "-1").Selected = "false";
        dropdownItems2.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";
    }
    else if (rowNumber == 3)
        dropdownItems3.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";
    else if (rowNumber == 4)
        dropdownItems4.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";
    else if (rowNumber == 5)
        dropdownItems5.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";
    else if (rowNumber == 6)
        dropdownItems6.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";
    else if (rowNumber == 7)
        dropdownItems7.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";
    else if (rowNumber == 8)
        dropdownItems8.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";
    else if (rowNumber == 9)
        dropdownItems9.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";
    else if (rowNumber == 10)
        dropdownItems10.Find(x => x.Value == _loaresponseitem.UtilityId.ToString()).Selected = "true";

    rowNumber++;
    if (rowNumber > 10)
        break;
}




tRole.Tabs = new Tabs()
{
  TextTabs = _listText,
  ListTabs = new List<List>()
  {
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility1", ListItems = dropdownItems1 },      
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility2", ListItems = dropdownItems2 },
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility3", ListItems = dropdownItems3 },
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility4", ListItems = dropdownItems4 },
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility5", ListItems = dropdownItems5 },
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility6", ListItems = dropdownItems6 },
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility7", ListItems = dropdownItems7 },
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility8", ListItems = dropdownItems8 },
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility9", ListItems = dropdownItems9 },
    new List(){ TabLabel = "ddlUtility10", ListItems = dropdownItems10 }
  }
};
tRole.Email = recipientEmail;
tRole.Name = recipientName;
tRole.RoleName = templateRoleName;
List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() { tRole };
envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;
envDef.TemplateId = TemplateId;
envDef.Status = "sent";
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(cfi);
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountID, envDef);
```

Comment: Are you facing the same issue when you download the file directly from the DocuSign website instead of the API?

Comment: No, But the selected dropdown values overlaps with nearby textbox.

Comment: Can you please share your envelope creation request. Are you facing this issue in the Sandbox (Demo) environment.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently working in Sandbox(Demo) environment.
And I'm populating the dropdown list items and some of the textbox values at run time. And I'm updating the question with create envelope code.

Comment: @CodingDawg I've re-updated the question with my code.

Comment: THanks @animesh Ananad... Can you please also share the envelopeId that you created and the templateId you are using.

Comment: Template Id--> 12a7b2d5-c650-4b2a-88ed-c87454e95429
Envelope Id--> d6b62a27-08b7-40e3-91fa-a280c2dff138

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154764/discussion-between-animesh-anand-and-codingdawg).

Comment: @CodingDawg We are about to go live with DocuSign and still I've not been able to resolve the mentioned issues, please help me out.

Comment: I am in the chat room if you want to join.